# How to properly curl this url?

Tags: curl, post, get, grep

Im trying to

```
curl -L https://www.kvb.koeln/qr/236/
```

to grep some specific parts but everything I get is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /qr/236
on this server.<br />
</p>
</body></html>
```

The URL works in the browser so I suspect I have some request/query to do but I can't figure out the right syntax. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The owner of the site is most likely blocking developer tools like curl. You want to try and pretend you are a browser using User-Agent header

Try the following:

```
curl -X GET \
  https://www.kvb.koeln/qr/236/ \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36'
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution. The server seems to check the UserAgent. In order to provide one during query I did:

```
curl -L -A "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.112 Safari/534.30" https://www.kvb.koeln/qr/236
```